# How does "substituting $x=x$" change the behavior of this Sage function?

Tags: recurrence-relations, sagemath

**TL/DR**: Why do the Sage functions defined below behave differently?

Consider the following recursively-defined sequence of functions, $g_n: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$:
$$
g_0(x) = 1,
$$
and for $n\geq 1$,
$$
g_n(x) = \int_0^x g_{n-1}(x-t)  \, dt.
$$
We can prove by induction that $g_n(x) = \frac{1}{n!}x^n$, for all $n$ and $x$.  For the induction step, treat $x$ as fixed and substitute $u = x-t$, $du= -dt$.  Alternatively, we could use [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) to show that $g_n'(x) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$, and then note that $g_n(0) = 0$.  There may be other approaches.

So, the result is not in doubt.  My question is about how one might check this result in [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org).

Here is an implementation that seems to work:

```
t = var('t')
x = var('x')

def g(n):
    if n == 0:
        return lambda x: 1
    else:
        expression = integral(g(n-1)(x-t), t, 0, x)
        return lambda x: expression.subs(x=x)
```

For example if I do `g(8)(1)`, I get `1/40320`.  This is the correct result, because $8!=40320$.  (Here I am implementing $g_8$ as `g(8)`, so technically `g` is a function which takes natural numbers to functions--in other words, `g` is a sequence of functions.)

Here's one that doesn't work (with `t`,`x` defined as above):

```
def h(n):
    if n == 0:
        return lambda x: 1
    else:
        expression = integral(h(n-1)(x-t), t, 0, x)
        return lambda x: expression
```

Now `h(8)(1)` gives `x^8`, which clearly is not what I want, because $g_8(1)$ should not have any free variables!  But the only difference between these two versions is the `.subs(x=x)` in the last line, so I guess my question is:

*How does "substituting $x$ for $x$" cause different behavior?*

I suspect that the issue is some kind of subtlety about reusing the same variable name at different levels of recursion, but I still would have (naïvely) expected the two versions to either both work or both fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, there is a difference between the functions

```
a = lambda x: expression.subs(x=x)
```

and

```
b = lambda x: expression
```

where `expression` is a symbolic expression which is defined in terms of some variable `var('x')`.

Namely, e.g. `a(5)` evaluates to `expression.subs(x=5)`, whereas `b(5)` evaluates to `expression` which will still depend on `var('x')` because no substitution is done.
Note `b` does not use its argument at all, whereas `a` passes its argument as a keyword argument to `subs` where the key has the name `'x'` (corresponding to the name of the variable which you want to substitute). Your confusion is probably due to the names of the `lambda`s arguments. The above are equivalent to:

```
a = lambda z: expression.subs(x=z)
```

and

```
b = lambda z: expression
```

which makes it clearer what happens.

Comment: +1, Thanks, this is excellent! (I'll leave the question open a bit longer, and then most likely accept this answer.)  I think it was not obvious to me that `a(5)` would evaluate to `expression.subs(x=5)`, rather than, say, `expression.subs(5=5)` or something (which would likely produce an error, but anyway).  I think I just didn't understand `.subs()` very well.  So I'll think about that and then maybe ask a different question if necessary.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! For that you should also understand keyword arguments in Python.